# Bootstrap jumbotron attached with left arrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a jumbotron (maybe use another component) with left arrow attached that's pointing to the text in the left another column.

The image bellow shows exactly what i'm trying to do.

How exactly does this work and how is it accomplished?

[left-arrow-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5OrG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using another component with customized border attribute.

For example,

CSS:

```
.jumbo {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.jumbo .arrow {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -5px;
    left: 110%;
}

.arrow::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbo">
    <span class="arrow">Jumbotron</span>
</div>
```

P.S. You may need to adjust the attributes to fit your needs.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x4xrqon/1/)

Comment: did you try this yourself? - it don't look too good...

Comment: Yes I did. However, you may need to adjust the attributes to fit your needs. I added the jsfiddle.